# How to implement circle over mapView, as is done with the reminders app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mkmapview

I'm trying to make something like Apple's stock reminders app. Here there is a mapView with a radius circle that is resizable by dragging. Does anyone have any idea how to something like this? Is it an overlay? How does it get resized with a drag?
[image]